# How do I write queries on json fields using equals, like and not equal?

Tags: mysql, go-gorm

I have a column as a json type. Within the json data, there are several columns. We want to be able to query the data using equals, like and not equal operators. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Keep in mind, in this case, the column name is also dynamic and thus I cannot hardcode it in the where clause.

```
func applyServerLogsQuery(db *gorm.DB, logType api.LogDestination_LogType, req *logs.GetLogsRequest) (*gorm.DB, error) {
    // set log type
    db = db.Where("log_type = ?", logType)

    // check for time
    if !req.StartTime.IsZero() {
        db = db.Where("time_stamp >= ?", req.StartTime)
    }

    if !req.EndTime.IsZero() {
        db = db.Where("time_stamp <= ?", req.EndTime)
    }

    // process filters
    for _, filter := range req.Filters {
        if len(filter.Values) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        property := filter.PropertyInfo.Name
        value := filter.Values[0]

        switch filter.FilterType {
        case logs.FilterTypeRegex:
            db = db.Where("log->>$? like ?", property, value)

        case logs.FilterTypeShould:
            db = db.Where("log->>$? = ?", property, value)

        case logs.FilterTypeExclude:
            db = db.Where("log->>$? != ?", property, value)
        }

        /*
            prefix := fmt.Sprintf("log->>'$.%s'", filter.PropertyInfo.Name)
            value := filter.Values[0]
            queryString := fmt.Sprintf("log->>'$.%s' like '%s'", filter.PropertyInfo.Name, value)

            log.Printf("Prefix %s value %s query %s", prefix, value, queryString)

            switch filter.FilterType {
            case logs.FilterTypeRegex:
                db = db.Where(queryString)
            }
        */
    }

    // handle order by time
    orderStr := "time_stamp"
    if req.OrderDesc {
        orderStr = fmt.Sprintf("%s desc", orderStr)
    } else {
        orderStr = fmt.Sprintf("%s asc", orderStr)
    }
    db = db.Order(orderStr)

    // handle limit
    db = db.Limit(int(req.Limit))

    return db, nil
}
```

The MySQL query is malformed -
SELECT * FROM `server_logs` WHERE log_type = 2 AND time_stamp >= '2023-03-10 15:55:14.304' AND time_stamp <= '2023-03-10 15:55:24.441' AND log->>$'severity' = 'High' ORDER BY time_stamp desc

The issue is the escaping  - it should be log->>'$.severity'

If I try to construct the query string using fmt.Sprintf, it works but ofcourse we are exposed to SQL injection.

```
prefix := fmt.Sprintf("log->>'$.%s'", filter.PropertyInfo.Name)
            value := filter.Values[0]
            queryString := fmt.Sprintf("log->>'$.%s' like '%s'", filter.PropertyInfo.Name, value)

            log.Printf("Prefix %s value %s query %s", prefix, value, queryString)

            switch filter.FilterType {
            case logs.FilterTypeRegex:
                db = db.Where(queryString)
            }
```

In the above case, the correct query string is generated.

Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `->` or `->>` operators do not accept expressions or parameters. They only accept JSON path as a string literal. So you must use `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(...))`.

I would suggest formatting the JSON path in a Go expression before passing it as the parameter.

```
db = db.Where("json_unquote(json_extract(log, ?)) like ?",
  "$."+property, value)
```

An alternative is to use CONCAT() to format the JSON path, and pass the property alone as the parameter.

```
db = db.Where("json_unquote(json_extract(log, concat('$.', ?))) like ?",
  property, value)
```

Comment: That  was a great suggestion Bill. I think this should be part of the gorm documentation.

Comment: IMO, if you're referencing a JSON column in a WHERE clause at all, you should reconsider your design.

Comment: Bill thank you for the note there. If I need to filter the rows by a criteria inside the column, what is the alternative? Otherwise all those columns from JSON have to be stored as individual columns in the MySQL table.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. In a relational database, use normal rows and columns. Don't use JSON and expect the fields within the JSON document to be as easy to use as normal columns.

Comment: JSON in a relational database means you have to write expressions to simulate all the typical things you would do with rows and columns. It's an example of the [Inner-platform effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Comment: Not sure I agreee. If that is the case, why store a document as JSON? We can as well extract all the fields from the JSON and store as individual columns.

Comment: Some applications need to store "semi-structured" data if the fields are variable, or if the data format contains nested structures. That's fine. But once you try to use the fields within a JSON document for searching, sorting, joining, etc. then the queries get difficult to write and difficult to optimize. My general recommendation is: reference the JSON column _only_ in the select-list. Not in a WHERE clause, or any other clause of the query.